# Plugins not working on rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a template I have installed and everything is working except some of the javascript, but when I check the compiled list of javascript I see all files have loaded and the css has all the correct files. What is the best way to troubleshoot and figure out how to get the js to load and figure what the problem is?

Here is my application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require js/template
//= require bootstrap/js/bootstrap
//= require plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution
//= require plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.enablelog
//= require plugins/isotope/isotope.pkgd
//= require magnific-popup
//= require plugins/SmoothScroll
//= require plugins/modernizr
//= require plugins/jquery.validate
//= require plugins/jquery.parallax-1.1.3
//= require plugins/jquery.min
//= require plugins/jquery.knob.min
//= require plugins/jquery.countTo
//= require plugins/jquery.browser
//= require owl.carousel
//= require js/custom
//= require js/coming.soon.config
//= require js/google.map.config
//= require bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min
//= require bootstrap/js/npm
//= require plugins/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.min
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/bootstrap/js
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/js
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/plugins/bootstrap-notify
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/plugins/charts
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/plugins/jasny-bootstrap/js
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/plugins/jquery.countdown
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/plugins/morphext
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/plugins/vide
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/template/plugins
```

Also here is my application.css.scss file

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "css/style";
@import "plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings-ie8";
@import "css/animate";
@import "plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings";
@import "css/animations";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "fontello";
@import "plugins/morphext/morphext";


 /*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require magnific-popup
 *= require owl.carousel
 *= require owl.theme
 *= require owl.transitions
 *= require_directory ./plugins/hover
 *= require animate
 *= require jquery.countdown
 *= require 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'
 *= require '/fonts/font-awesome/font-awesome.scss'
 *= require_directory ./fonts/fontello/css
 *= require_directory ./plugins/jasny-bootstrap/css
 *= require_directory ./plugins/morphext
 *= require_directory ./css/skins
 *= require_directory ./css
 *= require hover
 */
```

The page is suppose to look like this http://htmlcoder.me/preview/the_project/v.1.1/template/features-sliders-video-background.html#

But the scrolling video wont work or the fade in on the boxes. Not sure what to do first.

Here is what the console shows

> Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML   Rendered
>   welcome/__manager_slideshow.html.erb (0.1ms)   Rendered
>   welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (14.5ms) Completed
>   200 OK in 4392ms (Views: 4391.3ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:20 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:20 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:20 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.purr.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:21 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/best_in_place.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:21 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.autosize.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:21 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:22 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:22 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:22 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:22 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:22 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/animate.css" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:23
>   +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:23 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:23 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:23 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:23 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:23 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:24 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:24 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:24 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:24 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/revolution-slider/jquery.themepunch.enablelog.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:25 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/revolution-slider/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:25 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/revolution-slider/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:25 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/revolution-slider/index.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2
>   at 2015-12-10 05:44:25 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/isotope/isotope.pkgd.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:26 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/magnific-popup.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:26 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/SmoothScroll.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:26 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/modernizr.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:27 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.validate.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:27 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:27 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:28 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.knob.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:28 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countTo.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:28 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.browser.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:28 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/owl.carousel.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:29 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/custom.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:29 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/coming.soon.config.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:29 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/google.map.config.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:29 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:29 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/js/npm.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:30 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.min.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:30 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/js/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:30 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/template.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:30 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:31 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/charts/Chart.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:31 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/charts/Chart.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:31 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2
>   at 2015-12-10 05:44:31 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jasny-bootstrap/js/jasny-bootstrap.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:31 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jasny-bootstrap/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:32 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countdown/jquery.countdown.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:32 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:33 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countdown/jquery.plugin.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:33 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countdown/jquery.plugin.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:33 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:33 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:33 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/morphext/morphext.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:34 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/morphext/morphext.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:34 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2
>   at 2015-12-10 05:44:34 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:34 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/pace/pace.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:34 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.enablelog.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:34 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:35 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:35 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/vide/jquery.vide.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:35 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/vide/jquery.vide.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:35 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:35 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:36 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:36 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/rails.validations.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:36 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:37 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.purr.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:37 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.autosize.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:37 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/best_in_place.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:37 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:37 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:37 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:38 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:38 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:38 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:38 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:38 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:38 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:39 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:39 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:39 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:39 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:39 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:40 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/revolution-slider/jquery.themepunch.enablelog.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:40 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/revolution-slider/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:40 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/revolution-slider/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:40 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/revolution-slider/index.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2
>   at 2015-12-10 05:44:41 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/isotope/isotope.pkgd.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:41 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/magnific-popup.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:41 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/SmoothScroll.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:41 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/modernizr.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:41 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.validate.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:42 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:42 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:42 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.knob.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:42 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countTo.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:42 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.browser.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:43 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/owl.carousel.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:43 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/custom.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:43 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/coming.soon.config.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:43 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/google.map.config.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:43 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:43 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/js/npm.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:44 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.min.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:44 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/js/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:44 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/template.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:44 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:44 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/charts/Chart.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:45 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/charts/Chart.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:45 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2
>   at 2015-12-10 05:44:45 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jasny-bootstrap/js/jasny-bootstrap.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:45 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jasny-bootstrap/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:45 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countdown/jquery.countdown.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:46 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:46 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countdown/jquery.plugin.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:46 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/jquery.countdown/jquery.plugin.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:46 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js?body=1"
>   for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:46 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:46 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/morphext/morphext.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:47 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/morphext/morphext.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:47 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2
>   at 2015-12-10 05:44:47 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:47 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/pace/pace.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:47 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.enablelog.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:47 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:48 +0000
>
> Started GET
>   "/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:48 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/vide/jquery.vide.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:48 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/vide/jquery.vide.min.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:48 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:48 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js?body=1" for
>   10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10 05:44:49 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-12-10
>   05:44:49 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/rails.validations.js?body=1" for 10.0.2.2 at
>   2015-12-10 05:44:49 +0000
>
> Started GET "/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0" for 10.0.2.2
>   at 2015-12-10 05:44:49 +0000

So from what I see everything is loading with no errors. I also noticed that any objects with a class that has some javascript running such as

```
<div class="pv-30 ph-20 feature-box bordered shadow text-center object-non-visible" data-animation-effect="fadeInLeftSmall" data-effect-delay="100">
```

Never load because of the "object-non-visible" it never becomes visible which makes me further think some js is not loading or working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably due to [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), which is included by default in all Rails 4 apps. Turbolinks is great for load time, but since it overrides the normal page loading process, `jQuery.ready()` or `$(document).on('ready', ...` can't be relied on to execute code ([link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events)).

If you are able to modify the javascript to use the `page:change` event instead of `ready` that should work, or if you'd rather just remove turbolinks you can either take it away from a specific link by adding `data-no-turbolinks` to the anchor element, or remove it entirely [like so](https://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/how-to-remove-turbolinks-from-rails-4/).

You can also try checking out the [jquery.turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks), which aims to solve this problem.

Comment: Before I changed the javascript I removed the turbolinks as you suggested and got no change so I don't think that is it. Still not showing the slider after turbolinks was removed

Comment: Hmmm in that case, I'm not totally sure. Have you already tried inserting a `debugger` statement in the code block responsible to see if it is getting executed?

Comment: Its a slider so I put a debugger just in the code and nothing showed up same as before which again leads me to a javascript issue.

Comment: Sorry I mean a [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) in the Javascript code handling the slider, so you can see if that Javascript code is being executed.